Extract leaflet marker coordinates by web scraping
I am trying to get the coordinates of a marker displayed on a leaflet map with my web scraper. However, I am unable to access these values. When exploring the page in my console, I stumbled on #leaflet-marker-icon._leaflet_pos. This gives me an x and y value, but they seem to be relative to the map.
Is there a way to convert these to real world lat and long coordinates, without using the layerPointToLatLng method, as the leaflet methods do not seem to be exposed to the browser from what I can tell.
